# some radio button not working and some do

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I am new to PHP and I got error.I inserted radio button after the condition is checked (on MySQLi query) inside the `if statement` I inserted different radio buttons.First when I inserted 8 radio buttons than they were working perfectly now when I inserted 20 radio buttons than the top 3 radio buttons are not working and the rest are working!
I am confused what causing this error!

```
$qry = mysqli_query($con,"select user_pin,user_pin_entry from `user_data` where user_pin='$sms_code'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry);
 if ($row['user_pin']==$sms_code && $row['user_pin_entry']<=10) {
  $slct_data = mysqli_query($con,"select * from poll") or die(mysqli_erro($con));
    while ($row2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($slct_data)) {

      echo "<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 text-center back'>".$row2['poll_title']."</div>";

         if(!empty($row2["poll_1"]) && !empty($row2["poll_1_image"])){
        echo  "<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-sm-12 center'></br><img src='admin/uploads/".$row2["poll_1_image"]."'/><p>";
        echo $row2["poll_1"]."</p><input type='radio' name='poll[]' class='radio' value='male'/></div>";
    }

         if(!empty($row2["poll_2"]) && !empty($row2["poll_2_image"])){
        echo  "<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-sm-12 center'></br><img src='admin/uploads/".$row2["poll_2_image"]."'/><p>";
        echo $row2["poll_2"]."</p><input type='radio' name='poll[]' class='radio' value='male'/></div>";
    }

         if(!empty($row2["poll_3"]) && !empty($row2["poll_3_image"])){
        echo  "<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-sm-12 center'></br><img src='admin/uploads/".$row2["poll_3_image"]."'/><p>";
        echo $row2["poll_3"]."</p><input type='radio' name='poll[]' class='radio' value='male'/></div>";
    }

         if(!empty($row2["poll_4"]) && !empty($row2["poll_4_image"])){
        echo  "<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-sm-12 center'></br><img src='admin/uploads/".$row2["poll_4_image"]."'/><p>";
        echo $row2["poll_4"]."</p><input type='radio' name='poll[]' class='radio' value='male'/></div>";
    }

         if(!empty($row2["poll_5"]) && !empty($row2["poll_5_image"])){
        echo  "<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-sm-12 center'></br><img src='admin/uploads/".$row2["poll_5_image"]."'/><p>";
        echo $row2["poll_5"]."</p><input type='radio' name='poll[]' class='radio' value='male'/></div>";
    }

         if(!empty($row2["poll_6"]) && !empty($row2["poll_6_image"])){
          echo  "<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-sm-12 center'></br><img src='admin/uploads/".$row2["poll_6_image"]."'/><p>";
        echo $row2["poll_6"]."</p><input type='radio' name='poll[]' class='radio' value='male'/></div>";
    }

         if(!empty($row2["poll_7"]) && !empty($row2["poll_7_image"])){
        echo  "<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-sm-12 center'></br><img src='admin/uploads/".$row2["poll_7_image"]."'/><p>";
        echo $row2["poll_7"]."</p><input type='radio' name='poll[]' class='radio' value='male'/></div>";
    }

         if(!empty($row2["poll_8"]) && !empty($row2["poll_8_image"])){
        echo  "<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-sm-12 center'></br><img src='admin/uploads/".$row2["poll_8_image"]."'/><p>";
        echo $row2["poll_8"]."</p><input type='radio' name='poll[]' class='radio' value='male'/></div>";
    }

         if(!empty($row2["poll_9"]) && !empty($row2["poll_9_image"])){
        echo  "<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-sm-12 center'></br><img src='admin/uploads/".$row2["poll_9_image"]."'/><p>";
        echo $row2["poll_9"]."</p><input type='radio' name='poll[]' class='radio' value='male'/></div>";
    }

         if(!empty($row2["poll_10"]) && !empty($row2["poll_10_image"])){
        echo  "<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-sm-12 center'></br><img src='admin/uploads/".$row2["poll_10_image"]."'/><p>";
        echo $row2["poll_10"]."</p><input type='radio' name='poll[]' class='radio' value='male'/></div>";
    }

         if(!empty($row2["poll_11"]) && !empty($row2["poll_11_image"])){
        echo  "<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-sm-12 center'></br><img src='admin/uploads/".$row2["poll_11_image"]."'/><p>";
        echo $row2["poll_11"]."</p><input type='radio' name='poll[]' class='radio' value='male'/></div>";
    }

         if(!empty($row2["poll_12"]) && !empty($row2["poll_12_image"])){
        echo  "<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-sm-12 center'></br><img src='admin/uploads/".$row2["poll_12_image"]."'/><p>";
        echo $row2["poll_12"]."</p><input type='radio' name='poll[]' class='radio' value='male'/></div>";
    }

         if(!empty($row2["poll_13"]) && !empty($row2["poll_13_image"])){
        echo  "<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-sm-12 center'></br><img src='admin/uploads/".$row2["poll_13_image"]."'/><p>";
        echo $row2["poll_13"]."</p><input type='radio' name='poll[]' class='radio' value='male'/></div>";
    }

         if(!empty($row2["poll_14"]) && !empty($row2["poll_14_image"])){
        echo  "<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-sm-12 center'></br><img src='admin/uploads/".$row2["poll_14_image"]."'/><p>";
        echo $row2["poll_14"]."</p><input type='radio' name='poll[]' class='radio' value='male'/></div>";
    }

         if(!empty($row2["poll_15"]) && !empty($row2["poll_15_image"])){
        echo  "<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-sm-12 center'></br><img src='admin/uploads/".$row2["poll_15_image"]."'/><p>";
        echo $row2["poll_15"]."</p><input type='radio' name='poll[]' class='radio' value='male'/></div>";
    }

         if(!empty($row2["poll_16"]) && !empty($row2["poll_16_image"])){
        echo  "<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-sm-12 center'></br><img src='admin/uploads/".$row2["poll_16_image"]."'/><p>";
        echo $row2["poll_16"]."</p><input type='radio' name='poll[]' class='radio' value='male'/></div>";
    }

         if(!empty($row2["poll_17"]) && !empty($row2["poll_17_image"])){
        echo  "<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-sm-12 center'></br><img src='admin/uploads/".$row2["poll_17_image"]."'/><p>";
        echo $row2["poll_17"]."</p><input type='radio' name='poll[]' class='radio' value='male'/></div>";
    }

         if(!empty($row2["poll_18"]) && !empty($row2["poll_18_image"])){
        echo  "<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-sm-12 center'></br><img src='admin/uploads/".$row2["poll_18_image"]."'/><p>";
        echo $row2["poll_18"]."</p><input type='radio' name='poll[]' class='radio' value='male'/></div>";
    }

         if(!empty($row2["poll_19"]) && !empty($row2["poll_19_image"])){
        echo  "<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-sm-12 center'></br><img src='admin/uploads/".$row2["poll_19_image"]."'/><p>";
        echo $row2["poll_19"]."</p><input type='radio' name='poll[]' class='radio' value='male'/></div>";
    }

        if(!empty($row2["poll_20"]) && !empty($row2["poll_20_image"])){
    }
 }
}
 else {
    header("Location: wrong_pin.php");
 }
 }

 if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    echo $ip;
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    echo $ip;
} else {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    echo $ip;
}
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Vote Now"/>
</div>
</form>
  </div>
```

Comment: What are the code that works?

Comment: Please post more related-code!

Comment: my code is for voting system.
first i checked the condition if database have an image and name than insert me radio button.if no image and name than do not run that part (radio button). currently i have an empty fields in database table.is that the cause???

Comment: let me add some more code that you may get what i am try to creating.

Comment: Include the error you are getting as well.

Comment: Do you mean to say you have empty record in the database and it is still executing the radio buttons  part? And what is the error?

Comment: I think you want `&&` not `||`.

Comment: i have empty records.for that radio button's are not displayed (that's ok) but for the first 7 records (which is displayed) in that 3 radio buttons are not working and 4 are working correctly.3 are unable to select.

Comment: @chris85 error is ( total 7 radio buttons display but 4 are working and 3 are not)

Comment: @chris85 i will do that changes right now and will let you know.

Comment: That's probably not the exact issue but I'm not sure what you mean. Your current logic fails because your first condition is nullified by the second and vice versa.

Comment: @chris85 `&&` doesn't help!
still unable to select from the top 3 radio buttons.4 radio button's are working but top 3 are not.

Comment: There are only 3 radio buttons here so I have no idea what the difference is between the working 4.

Comment: @chris85 i tried that too.
in first 8 condition, 7 were true and one was not than the code was working perfectly (able to select from all radio buttons) but after when i inserted more condition's this fault occur!

Comment: i will add all code now @chris85

Comment: @hassangul don't forget to use else-if too.

Comment: @chris85 please have a look `code` updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are messing up with `||` and `&&` 
In case of `||` the `if-statement` is executed if anyone of the condition is met (true). On the other hand it is executed only if both of the conditions are true when `&&` is used. 
Try this:

```
if(!empty($row2["poll_1"]) && !empty($row2["poll_1_image"])){
    echo  "<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-sm-12 center'></br><img src='admin/uploads/".$row2["poll_1_image"]."'/>";
    echo $row2["poll_1"]."</p><input type='radio' name='poll[]' class='radio' value='male'/></div>";
}
```

**EDIT:** 
You had error in your opening/closing `<p>` tags, kindly use the proper syntax.

Comment: this is not the problem.problem is 3 out of 7 radio buttons are not working.

Comment: @hassangul kindly post the code with all the 7 buttons and highlight which three aren't working

Comment: @hassangul what exactly is the difference in the first three conditions and the rest in your database? Can you elaborate that please?

Comment: there is no difference in the first three and the rest of 4. from total 20 database entries 7 are filled in the database and inserted to the front.but the top 3 inserted radio button can't be selected from mean not working.

Comment: Do you mean the first three radio types have the entries stored in the database? And the 7 filled in database entries are working fine, which ones are they?

Comment: please update it that i may accept it as a correct answer!
by removing `<p>` tag error resolve.please change your answer that i may accept it.thank you

Answer (score 0):

@hassan gul consider @chris85 comment. You currently have an OR condition:

```
if(!empty($row2["poll_1"]) || !empty($row2["poll_1_image"]))
```

This means that if either poll_1 or poll_1_image actually have a value, you will display what is insed the if statement

```
if(!empty($row2["poll_1"]) && !empty($row2["poll_1_image"]))
```

Only displays IF both of the above have a value (e.g: you were able to return it from the database).

If your goal is for all of them to work and be displayed, then you need to have data in the db table you are reading from for all the rows

Comment: this is not the problem. problem is i am unable to select from the first 3 inserted radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest making concrete array keys that correlate to your `poll[]` inputs (so for example they would be `poll[poll_1]` ect. This may or may not help, it depends on what you are doing when you process the input after submission), and secondly make a function with a `for` loop. I can't decipher if you do or don't need `||` or `&&` but it looks like you need `&&`:

```
<?php
    // Put this function declaration at the top of the page.
    // Better would be to put it on entirely different page and include the page at the top
    function makecheckbox($array = false, $key = false)
        {
            if(!empty($array[$key]) && !empty($array[$key."_image"])) { ?>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-sm-12 center"><br />
                <img src="admin/uploads/<?php echo $array[$key."_image"]; ?>"/>
                <p><?php echo $array[$key]; ?></p>
                <input type="radio" name="poll[<?php echo $key; ?>]" class="radio" value="male"/>
            </div>
            <?php
                }
        }
?>
```

**To use in your code:**

```
    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($slct_data)) {
        echo "<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 text-center back'>".$row2['poll_title']."</div>";

        // Inside your while, use a for in place of all your "if" conditions
        for($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++)
            makecheckbox($row2,'poll_'.$i);
    }
```

If you create a function, you will be almost guaranteed that your output is the same *(you may copy and paste wrong or change one line and forget to change others....etc.)*. It also cleans up your page and makes spotting syntax errors easier.

Comment: you are right.
please provide me full syntax as i am new and don't have use such a loop before.thank you rasclatt once again.
i solved the error by removing all `<p> and </p>` tags.

Comment: The syntax is the what I wrote. Put the function declaration (top snippit) at the top of your page (or another page that gets included), then you replace your whole while statement with what I have (copy yours first and set it aside before you outright replace yours).

Comment: Removing all your paragraph tags is a weird fix for your problem that was going on. You should be able have `<p>` in there where you have it (unless you have some crazy `css` on it)

Comment: no i don't have some crazy css.when i remove `<p>` than i am able to select the top 3 radio box.first it was not working by removing `<p>` tag it start work.

Comment: Yeah there is something strange going on. Do you maybe have an unclosed `<p>` somewhere else on the page maybe? Did you try my reduced code?

Comment: i have another question for you please help me out in that.
i want user input to insert into database from 20 radio box.mean i only want to filter the single result which user will select and enter submit and than i want to select that user submitted data (1 radio button value) and insert that to database.how i can do that?
thank you.

Comment: Not sure I understand. So if someone checks one box only, you just want that one box value to insert into your database?

Comment: yes.i want to do that on another page.`<form method="post" action="vote_submit.php">` i want to do this on `submit.php` page!

Comment: waiting for your answer!

Comment: What part do you not know how to do? Insert into the database or what part of the process are not sure of?

Comment: how can i get single result from all of 20 radio buttons.i want only single result from that which user submit and later i will insert that result to database with a lot of condition's :)